Construct a circle through A, B, intersecting circle C at diameter.
Given a circle C and two points A and B in general position in the plane, construct a circle
through A and B which intersects C in two points which are ends of a diameter of C.
My first attempt was to suppose circle C is defined by $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$, and suppose point A had coordinates $(x_A, y_A)$, point B with coordinates $(x_B, y_B)$. But I thought I introduced too many variables and this approach wouldn't work. Any ideas?

Without loss of generality, you can assume that $C$ is the unit circle and that $A$ and $B$ are both on a horizontal line $y = c$. (Implicitly, imagine you have defined a coordinate system in terms of which  those conditions hold.) That start should get you what you need.

(RobinSparrow's solution is much easier and direct, so look at that instead.)
Consider the circles

$C$ of radius $r$, with center $O$.
$C_1$ of diameter $AB$, with center $P$.
$C_2$ which passes through $A, B, E, F$ where $EF$ is a diameter of $C$.

The radical center of these circles would be:

Along the radical axis of $C_1, C_2$, which is the line $APB$.
Along the radical axis of $C_1, C$, which is perpendicular to $PO$.
Along the radical axis of $C_2, C$, which is the line $EOF$.

So let $AB$ and the radical axis of $C_1, C$ intersect at point $D$, which is the radical center of these circles. Then, $DO$ will intersect $C$ at the points $E, F$.
So, it just remains to determine the radical axis of 2 general circles. This is well known and  left to the reader.
Here is a picture in the easier case when $C_1, C$ intersect, as the radical axis is the line along their intersections. With the variable points $A, B, O$ and radius $r$, we defined $D, E, F$ as above, then verified that $A, B, E, F$ are concyclic.


Say $O$ is the center of the given circle $C_1$ of radius $r$ and we seek to define the circle $C_x$. Draw the line $AO$. Now, suppose the solution exists such that $AO$ extended met the qualifying circle $C_x$ at $D$. Then also a diameter $EOE'$ of $C_1$ cuts $AD$ at $O$. Because chords divide each other into segments whose products are equal, in $C_x$ we then have $AO \times OD=EO \times OE'=r^2$. So construct or calculate $\frac{r^2}{AO}$, draw a circle $C_2$ of that radius on $O$, and where $C_2$ meets $AO$ extended is point $D$. Circumscribe $ABD$ and you have $C_x$.

